# How do I generate a temporary page like confirmation page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise and want to redirect users to a confirmation page upon signup, this is what I am doing right now:

users/registrations_controller.html.erb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def confirm_email
 end

 private

 def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  users_confirmyouremail_path
 end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do     
  get 'users/confirmyouremail' => 'users/registrations#confirm_email' 
end
```

I have no problem with redirecting the page after signup. However, I think it is quite weird that anyone can visit the page with url like `host.com/confirmyouremail' and see the confirmation page. Are there any ways I can write a route that will use random code that is allow only for one time visit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this page should just require authentication?  
And you can store somewhere in db that user already confirm your rules. So the page should not be showed to him once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

def confirm_mail
    redirect_to root_path if current_user.confirmed
...
end
```

You are storing in the database if the user has already confirmed his account. If his account is confirmed then he won't be able to access this page. You can redirect to whatever page you want. A user without any account won't be able to access this page because of the before action

In case the user is not logged in when he accesses this confirm_mail page you have different possibilities. You could use a session or a cookie:

```
# after sign up:
session[:confirm] = true
# alternatively a cookie
cookies[:confirm] = true
```

Then in the confirm mail action:

```
def confirm_mail
  if session[:confirm].blank? # or cookies[:confirm].blank?
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  # otherwise delete the field from the session
  session.delete(:confirm)
  # alternatively the cookie
  cookies.delete(:confirm)
end
```

Another way would be by using a Token. You create a new model like `ConfirmMailToken`. Then on sign up you create a new token and redirect the user to the confirm page with the token as a URL param. Then in the confirm_mail action you check if a token is available and delete it if it is. This way you ensure that the page is only shown after redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What if for example in my case, Users are not signed in yet when they successfully signed up and  redirect to the confirmation page which ask them to confirm their email?